# How to clone a list in event handler C#

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, eventhandler

I'm trying to access a List that contains the data I retrieved from a firebase database. To get this List from OnDataChanged method of Xamarin.Firebase.Database NuGet package, I used an event handler however I need to access that list out of the event handler. Is this possible? How can I get the list from event handler?

```
class PickData : IDbData
{
        AndroidData androidData;
        public List<string> topDbOut = new List<string>();


        public void GetData( string dataLoc, string dataLoc2, string dataLoc3, int level)
        {
            if(level == 1) 
            {
                androidData = new AndroidData(dataLoc, dataLoc2, dataLoc3, 1);
                androidData.Create();
                androidData.Retrieved += AndroidData_Retrieved;
            }
        }

        private void AndroidData_Retrieved(object sender, AndroidData.AndroDataEventArgs e)
        {
            topDbOut = e.Top;
        }

        public List<string> RetList()
        {
            return topDbOut;
        }
}
```

In this code `e.Top` is a `List<string>` and I want to clone that list to `topDbOut` and return `topDbOut` by using the RetList method.

I tried many different ways however, I cannot even modify a variable in event handler.

Comment: How about, in your event handler: `topDbOut = e.Top.ToList();` (you need a `using System.Linq;` for that)

Comment: @MatthewWatson It worked for calls in event handler however, not for calls in  `GetData` I may try to deep copy `topDbOut` in a new method called by event handler. I guess this is caused by the scope but I'm not sure.